# Center Subfigure Based on Included Graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, draw

I have a figure in my dissertation in which I am including a picture that has a bunch of labels identifying different aspects of the picture, some are long and some are short. The problem is that some of these labels are long and cause the entire image to be offset as shown below.
[image]
I would like to have the image itself (excluding the labels that I add to it) to be center aligned. How can I do this?

Here is a MWE that is basically the same as what I am doing in my document.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0](image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \node[anchor=east,align=right,draw=none] at (-0.10,0.80) {A loooooooooong label};
    \node[anchor=west,align=left ,draw=none] at ( 1.10,0.05) {Short Label};
    \draw[black,->,thick] (-0.10,0.80) -- (0.40,0.70);  %Outlet expansion line
    \draw[black,->,thick] ( 1.10,0.05) -- (0.30,0.10);  %Seeding array line
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{subfig1}}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig1}
\caption{An off-center figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `\rlap` and `\llap` where relevant (and `\centering` to centre the image itself, of course):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0](image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
      \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=east,align=right,draw=none] at (-0.10,0.80) {\llap{A loooooooooong label}};
        \node[anchor=west,align=left ,draw=none] at ( 1.10,0.05) {\rlap{Short Label}};
        \draw[black,->,thick] (-0.10,0.80) -- (0.40,0.70); %Outlet expansion line
        \draw[black,->,thick] ( 1.10,0.05) -- (0.30,0.10); %Seeding array line
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{subfig1}}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig1}
  \caption{An off-center figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both answers work but I chose this one because I do have some figures that have labels above and below.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\centering` at the start of the `subfigure`, and then add `\useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west);` in the `tikzpicture` just before the `scope`. This way the bounding box of the `tikzpicture` is defined only by the size of the image.

By the way, `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, and `tikz` loads `graphicx`. Therefore you don't actually have to load the latter two after `\usepackage{pgfplots}`. Also, it is recommended to use a specific version for `compat`, not `compat=newest`. The reason for this is that if `pgfplots` is updated, the look of your plot may change even if the code doesn't.

I just realized one thing: This doesn't work that well if you have labels above or below the image. It can be fixed manually by using `\useasboundingbox ([yshift=-1cm]image.south east) rectangle ([yshift=1cm]image.north west);` instead, modifying `1cm` and `-1cm` to useful lengths, which depends on the label positions. In that sense Bernard's answer is better.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0](image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west);
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \node[anchor=east,align=right,draw=none] at (-0.10,0.80) {A loooooooooong label};
    \node[anchor=west,align=left ,draw=none] at ( 1.10,0.05) {Short Label};
    \draw[black,->,thick] (-0.10,0.80) -- (0.40,0.70);  %Outlet expansion line
    \draw[black,->,thick] ( 1.10,0.05) -- (0.30,0.10);  %Seeding array line
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{subfig1}}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig1}
\caption{An off-center figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]